# How to search rows by months with checkbox in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to use arrays...

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="01">January
        <input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="02">Feb
        <input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="03">March
        <input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="04">April
        <input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="05">May
        <input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="06">June
        <input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="07">July
        <input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="08">August
        <input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="09">September
        <input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="10">Oct
        <input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="11">Nov
        <input type="checkbox" name="mes[]" value="12">Dec
        <input type="submit" name="reporte_mes">
    </form>
```

Part of php-mysql code:

```
if(isset($_POST['reporte_mes'])){

$busqueda_cad = implode(',', $_POST["mes"]);

$sql = "SELECT bien_catal.bien, categorias.nombre_categoria, 
marca_catal.marca, color_catal.color, modelo_catal.modelo, 
area_catal.area, condicion.condicion, products.caracteristicas, 
products.stock, products.precio_producto, products.date_added,
products.codigo_producto, products.observaciones FROM products 
LEFT JOIN bien_catal ON (products.fk_bien = bien_catal.id_bien) 
LEFT JOIN categorias ON (products.fk_categoria = categorias.id_categoria)  
LEFT JOIN marca_catal ON (products.fk_marca = marca_catal.id_marca)
LEFT JOIN color_catal ON (products.fk_color = color_catal.id_color)
LEFT JOIN modelo_catal ON (products.fk_modelo = modelo_catal.id_modelo)
LEFT JOIN area_catal ON (products.fk_area = area_catal.id_area)
LEFT JOIN condicion ON (products.fk_condicion = condicion.id_condicion)
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(products.date_added, '$busqueda_cad')";
```

The query is fine and it shows all rows without the WHERE, but from WHERE, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: If check a couple of months you var_dump out $_POST['mes'] what do you get

Comment: @UsmanShahid  array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "06"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "07"
}

Comment: So its echo'ing out correctly...If you echo out your $sql statement and then manually run that in PHPMyAdmin - does it work? I bet it doesn't, and that should be how you can debug it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't your variable `$busqueda_cad` an array of the months? So your `WHERE` is looking at the column `products.date_added` and trying to match it to a month?

I think it should be something like this with [COLUMN OF MONTHS] the column that holds your months of course

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( [COLUMN OF MONTHS] , '$busqueda_cad')";
```

Comment: Ohh. The column date.added is "date"... as 2017/07/19.

Comment: So your query is looking for the items in the "$busqueda_cad" array to match "2017/07/19". Which will never really match

Comment: Thank you. :) It was:    WHERE MONTH(products.date_added) = '$busqueda_cad'";